# What's the number of FFTs in Welch-based PSD?

Tags: power-spectral-density

I've read from the book "Proakis, J. G., & Manolakis, D. G. (2004). Digital signal processing. PHI Publication: New Delhi, India." Chapter 12 that the number of FFTs required for estimating the PSD from Welch method with 50% overlap is $2N/M$ where $N$ is the amount of data that you have from the signal, $M$ the size of the segments you choose for the method and I guess the $2$ is for the 50% overlap but from the articles I've read they usually do one FFT less than the one described in the equation, why is that? or what am I missing from this interpretation? My theory is that maybe the FFT missing it's supposed to be done with the last 50% of the data and another 50% of data completed with zero padding. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should really be 1 less than 2N/M. There's nothing to overlap the last "half-transform" (N/M) worth of samples.

You're also right, one could zero-pad that, but then that wouldn't be an Welch estimate.

So, I'll do something I rarely do: Blame Proakis for this :)

Answer (score 1):

The source paper is P. Welch: [The use of fast Fourier transform for the estimation of power spectra: A method based on time averaging over short, modified periodograms](https://doi.org/10.1109/TAU.1967.1161901)

> The use of the fast Fourier transform in power spectrum analysis is
> described. Principal advantages of this method are a reduction in the
> number of computations and in required core storage, and convenient
> application in nonstationarity tests. The method involves sectioning
> the record and averaging modified periodograms of the sections.

It clearly states the minus-one version:

[image]